# Micro VS Macro VS Weighted F1 Score

Tags: machine-learning, multiclass-classification, imbalanced-data

I have an imbalanced multi-classification dataset.
I calculated Micro F1, Macro F1 and Weighted F1.
I think Macro is the best when predicting overall performance on an imbalanced dataset.
But, Some people said use Micro if you want to see overall performance and others said Micro is only see when dataset is imbalanced.

1. Why Micro used in imbalanced datasets?
2. When do I use Micro, Macro, and Weighted?
   In other words, what circumstances are these means used?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2):

Firstly See this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/24051/112453)

Imbalanced data is always a big problem to deal with. Here is a binary classification of imbalanced data example. Overall accuracy looks great but when you look at individual scores you can see it is a big fail! For this kind of data I always check the minor class' scores before come up a result. You can consider data augmentation in this kind of data. There are good libraries to deal with imbalanced data. Here is a good example of a [library to deal with imbalanced data](https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/) in Python.

Finally, Micro avg use **individual** true and false positives also false negatives. Micro avg is just mean of presicion + recall and **does not consider the proportion of classes** in the data . So micro average reftlect the accuracy on imbalanced data better.

Note:

Here is an explanation in sklearn website:

**'micro':** Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.

**'macro':** Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account.

If you look at the macro, it says: **This does not take label imbalance into account.** So better to use micro if you have an imbalanced data.  [Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html)

```
#Confusion Matrix:
 [[3808    0]
 [ 182    2]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.95      1.00      0.98      3808
           1       1.00      0.01      0.02       184

    accuracy                           0.95      3992
   macro avg       0.98      0.51      0.50      3992
weighted avg       0.96      0.95      0.93      3992
```

Comment: don't Macro avg reflect imbalance data better? because, Macro avg calculate mean of F1. So I think Macro avg show the overall performance. but i'm not sure. please tell me if i am wrong.

Comment: I edited the answer please see Note part.

Comment: Do you know when to use Weighted?